# How can I customise the appearance of a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

I'd like to make a drop-down list that looks like this:

[image]

JComboBox provides the functionality I need, so I shouldn't need to write a custom component. But I can't find a way to customise the entire appearance of a JComboBox to achieve this. Any suggestions?

**Update**: I don't want all JComboBoxes to look like this. I only want to create one with this custom appearance. So as far as I can tell, creating a custom L&F is not the solution.

Comment: Have a look at the [Sun's Tutorial on LnFs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) for more details on Synth [How to Write A Custom Swing Component](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html)

Comment: @Stephane, I ended up creating a custom component.

Comment: i ran into the same problem... could you please share your custom component?

Answer (score 9):

JComboBox UI is composed from textfield, list and arrows.
To customize them you can use some ready L&F or implement your most easily with Synth L&F.

Initialize L&F:

```
SynthLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = new SynthLookAndFeel();

try {
    lookAndFeel.load(YourClassAlongWithSynthXml.class.getResourceAsStream("synth.xml"), YourClassAlongWithSynthXml.class);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
```

Where synth.xml contains something like this:

```
<style id="textfield">
    <insets top="4" left="6" bottom="4" right="6" />

    <state>
        <font name="Verdana" size="12" />

        <!--
        <color type="BACKGROUND" value="#D2DFF2" />
        -->
        <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#003c2d" />
    </state>

    <imagePainter method="textFieldBorder" path="images/textfield.png" sourceInsets="4 6 4 6" paintCenter="false" />
</style>

<bind style="textfield" type="region" key="TextField" />

<style id="arrowStyle">
    <imagePainter method="arrowButtonForeground" path="images/arrow-up.png" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" stretch="false" direction="north" />
    <imagePainter method="arrowButtonForeground" path="images/arrow-down.png" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" stretch="false" direction="south" />
    <imagePainter method="arrowButtonForeground" path="images/arrow-left.png" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" stretch="false" direction="west" />
    <imagePainter method="arrowButtonForeground" path="images/arrow-right.png" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" stretch="false" direction="east" />
</style>

<bind key="ArrowButton" type="region" style="arrowStyle" />

<style id="comboArrowStyle">
    <imagePainter method="arrowButtonForeground" path="images/combobox-arrow.png" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" stretch="false" direction="south" />
</style>
```

With Synth L&F you will need to fully define how your UI components look like you can't just.

But if you just need to simply modify colors reusing your default L&F, you can use the following snippets to initialize UI of combo box:

```
final Color COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND = Color.decode("#d3dedb");

UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonBackground", COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND);
UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonShadow", COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND);
UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonDarkShadow", COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND);
UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonHighlight", COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND);
```

Comment: This is good if I want to change the appearance of all combo boxes. But I want to just create one with this custom appearance.

Comment: How do you change the arrowStyle with the UIManager?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create an entire look and feel, the simplest answer is to subclass jcombobox and override the paintComponent method and draw whatever you want.

fill the background with your gray color, then draw your text and arrow in your lighter color.

if you go this route, you may also need to override the updateUI method so that if the VM tries to update your look and feel your combo box doesn't go back to the wrong colors.